# jQplot with tooltip for the peak value?

Tags: graph, highcharts, jqplot

Is there a way to display a tooltip or bubble as per the image below to show the highest value in the line graph? It should be visible at all time not just when roll over with the mouse.

Does jQplot support this? If not, is there any other graphing librabry that does this?

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: why is this tagged `highcharts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jqplot, this is possible using the `pointLabels` plugin:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var line1 = [[0,14,null],[1,32,null], [2,41,null], [3,44,'Hello World!'], [4,40,null], [5,47,null], [6,53,null], [7,67,null]]; // Only the 'Hello World' will have a label
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
      title: 'Chart with Point Labels', 
      seriesDefaults: { 
        showMarker:false,
        pointLabels: { show:true } 
      }
  });
});
```

CSS for bubble (from [here](http://www.ilikepixels.co.uk/drop/bubbler/)):

```
#chart1 .jqplot-point-label {
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #CC857E;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.jqplot-point-label:after 
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 10px 0;
    border-color: #CC857E transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 40px;
}
```

Produces this ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6yfG5/1/)):

[image]

Comment: I have a new question, can you help please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365000/what-is-the-correct-data-format-fro-jqplot-bar-stacked-chart

Answer (score 0):

In the highstock you can use flags like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/flags-placement)

Other options is using renderer to add custom shapes: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Renderer